# Somebody has worked with V4 Clio API retrieving reports?

Tags: clio-api

I'm trying to download some reports from Clio API through the API but I'm not even getting the path right for it, my request for the calendar, for example, works but not for reports.

Thanks

Comment: Show what you tried and what specifically does not work. This is currently very likely to be too vague to do anything with.

Comment: I've tried a get request to https://app.clio.com/api/v4/reports/  -  rsp was {"error":{"type":"NotFoundError","message":"Not Found"}}  also https://app.clio.com/api/v4/reports?fields=id - rps was  404 not found

Answer (score 1):

Without more detail regarding what you are trying to accomplish and what you've tried so far I'd suggest you just refer to the API documentation. According to the documentation the format to return the data for a single report should be https://app.clio.com/api/v4/reports/{id}.json where {id} is the id of the report to be retrieved.

If you are trying to download a completed report, the format is https://app.clio.com/api/v4/reports/{id}/download.json.